# Div not centering with CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to put some divs on the website, so it looks neat. There's one big div "container" and inside we have div "head", below it there's an empty div just to separate things and underneath it there's a div "content". My problem is: "head" is easily centered with "margin: 0 auto;", but the same line doesn't work in "content".

```css
#container
{
    background-color: darkorange;
    width: 70%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#head
{
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 95%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.space
{
    width: auto;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

#content
{
    background-color: forestgreen;
    width: 95%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="head">
                <div id="reg_welcome">
                    
                </div>
                <div id="logo">
                    
                </div>
                <div id="login_out">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space">
            </div>
            <div id="content">
              
            </div>
            <div class="space">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any idea why? (the colors are there just to see how it looks, please just ignore them)

And the second question, similar problem. Inside "head" there are three small divs that I want to float to left. Two of them behave as I want, the first one isn't even showed on the website. Here's the css for those three bits:

```css
#reg_welcome
{
    background-color: royalblue;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

#logo
{
    background-color: springgreen;
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
}

#login_out
{
    background-color: teal;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
            <div id="head">
                <div id="reg_welcome">
                    
                </div>
                <div id="logo">
                    
                </div>
                <div id="login_out">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space">
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                
            </div>
            <div class="space">
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

The oddest thing is here it all seems to work perfectly, but when ran on localhost, I have the problems I mentioned. Any idea why it happens?

Comment: You should also post the markup.

Comment: Edit the code snippets to include the HTML. Right now, clicking Run code snippet shows a blank page because there's nothing for the CSS to apply to.

Comment: You could use flexbox and use justify-content if you are not worried about supporting old versions of IE

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot about HTML code. The odd thing is that here the centering seems to work correctly, but when I run it on localhost, it refuses to cooperate...

Comment: Please ask one question per question. I see no issue with `#content` being centered. Off topic: Don't add markup to your page "just to separate things". That's what margin, padding, and borders are for.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to ask them together, cause the issue is similar. And as I said, here the problem seems to disappear, but when I run it on localhost, it's not centered and it's even more confusing now.

Comment: So the issue is apparently environmental and all that code is probably irrelevant. Is your CSS being loaded?

Comment: Probably it's not, but I felt safer adding it here, just in case the code was the problem. CSS is being loaded, yes. Actually I don't thing anything would work at all, if it didn't load, no? Is it possible that the host causes this problem?

Comment: Do you have a doctype? Maybe it doesn't work in your server because you don't have any, so the page is displayed in quirks mode.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE and it automatically added this one: <!DOCTYPE html> in the beginning of html file.